# Drop down works strange on mobile device

Tags: javascript, android, html, twitter-bootstrap, touchscreen

I'm building [this](http://www.marcellogiovenco.com) website with Bootstrap in which there is a drop down menu under "Projects" that is working fine on desktop PCs but on mobile devices it goes like this: the buttons opens at the touch and so does the menu "Projects" but then when tapping on one of the submenu items it does nothing and only a second tap will eventually open the desired submenu item. 
That means, you have to click twice to open a submenu link which is annoying.

Here is the **HTML** code:

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">     
   <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" id="myTabDrop1" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">PROJECTS</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="myTabDrop1">
          <li><a href="#napoli" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">NAPOLI</a></li>
          <li><a href="#portraits" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">PORTRAITS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li> 
    <li><a href="#bio" data-toggle="tab">BIO</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#contact" data-toggle="tab">CONTACT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#blablabla" data-toggle="tab">BLABLABLA</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Anyone could help here?

Comment: I can't even see your menu on mobile since `#myNavbar` gets `display:none`d on small screens. Also, you should be posting your source code, since your site is probably going to change, and future-people looking for a solution to the same problem won't be able to see the source.

Comment: @szupie I updated the question.
the site is being built with bootstrap that means the menu `mynavbar` will collapse on a button on small devices. So you should see a three lines button on the right of your screen close to the title of the site. If you click on it the menu opens. Do you see it?

Comment: I "see" now. The menu button is white on a white background, so it wasn't visible. It's working fine for me on Firefox 36 Android. The menu items open on one click. What browser are you using?

Comment: I use Android and tried both on Firefox and the default browser and I can see the three stripes on the right (I actually designed them with CSS). Anyway what happens when you click on Projects and then want to click on either Napoli or Portraits?

Comment: Odd, I can see the menu button now. In the future, you should post the minimum code required to reproduce the problem you have; the HTML code you posted by itself isn't enough to produce a "working" version. It's a pain to debug a live site without being able to change the code when you're on mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why this is an issue, but try adding this rule:

```
.dropdown-backdrop {
  z-index: -1;
}
```